# how to prefix a string before sequence generated by postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, sequence

This is a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE technician_id_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MINVALUE
NO MAXVALUE
CACHE 1;
```

It generates

1
2
3
4

I need the sequence as

AAA1
AAA2
AAA3
AAA4

Is it possible? I am very much new to postgresql.

Comment: Will it always be `AAA`? If so do it in the presentation layer.

Comment: Similar question here: why do you need a prefix?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto it will be change. I can do it in presentation layer. Just asking, whether it is possible with postgresql. it will save some effort

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to maintain the prefix on the presentation/UI layer? If somebody wants a differen prefix you can just tweak a template. If you put this stuff on DB then its much harder to change afterwards.

Comment: @jsalonen What is the best solution?? :)

Comment: It depends. If you only need the prefix as something that is shown to users, I'd put it on a template. If the prefix is something that you need to be able to search etc. then in that case I'd put it into database. I think you maybe need to describe your requirements more if you want a precise answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are a couple ways:

```
-- Referencing the sequence directly:
CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq;

SELECT 'AAAA'||nextval('test_seq')::TEXT;
 ?column? 
----------
 AAAA1

SELECT 'AAAA'||nextval('test_seq')::TEXT;
 ?column? 
----------
 AAAA2


-- Using a DEFAULT
CREATE TABLE abc 
    (val TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'AAAA'||nextval('test_seq'::regclass)::TEXT, 
    foo TEXT);

INSERT INTO abc (foo) VALUES ('qewr');

SELECT * FROM abc;
  val  | foo  
-------+------
 AAAA3 | qewr
```

These assume that you have carefully decided how to proceed, based on the comments to your original question, as asked by the others.